# jQuery Validation Engine not working when triggered using a link

Tags: jquery, triggers, click, submit, jquery-validation-engine

When I submit the form through a link (calling `submitlogin()`) it returns an AJAX error, but if I put `alert('hello')` after `submitlogin()`, it works. It appears as though AJAX is called twice when I trigger the submit this way. Can anyone explain how to use a link form submission of my AJAX form correctly?

**My Form:**

```
<form id="loginForm" name='loginForm' class=" clean" action="{$base_url}/login" method="post">
    <input  type="text" name="Username" id="Username" class=" field"  value="" size="23" />
    <input  type="password" name="Password" id="Password" class="field"  size="23" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="loginsubmit"  class="button icon-signin" value="Login" style="float:left;" />
    <a href=""  onclick="submitlogin();"  >Login</a>
</form>
```

**My jQuery Form Validation:**

```
$('#loginForm').validationEngine({ajaxFormValidation: true,
    ajaxFormValidationURL :BASE_URL+"login/submit/",
    onAjaxFormComplete: function(status, form, json, options)
    {
        if(status && json.false==null) // no error messages
        {
            window.location=BASE_URL;
        }
    },
    onBeforeAjaxFormValidation: beforeCall
});
```

Above works fine, when I click the submit `button` manually. But when I click the `link`, it fails. I have tried different versions of `submitlogin()`, all fail.

```
// 1
function submitlogin()
{
    $('#loginForm').validationEngine('triggersubmit');
    return false;
}    

// 2
function submitlogin()
{
    $('#loginForm').submit();
}       

// 3
function submitlogin()
{
    $('#loginForm').trigger('submit');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try the following:

```
$("#login_link").click(function() {

    $('#loginForm').validationEngine({ajaxFormValidation: true,
        ajaxFormValidationURL :BASE_URL+"login/submit/",
        onAjaxFormComplete: function(status, form, json, options)
        {
            if(status && json.false==null) // no error messages
            {
                window.location=BASE_URL;
            }
        },
        onBeforeAjaxFormValidation: beforeCall
    });

});
```

where `#login_link` is your link:

```
<form id="loginForm" name='loginForm' class=" clean" action="{$base_url}/login" method="post">
    <input  type="text" name="Username" id="Username" class=" field"  value="" size="23" />
    <input  type="password" name="Password" id="Password" class="field"  size="23" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="loginsubmit"  class="button icon-signin" value="Login" style="float:left;" />

    <!-- YOUR LINK "#login_link" -->
    <a href="" id="login_link" >Login</a>

</form>
```

Hope this will work for you. Let me know about your results mate.

Comment: That did not work. I tried before. Its basically rebooting..it throw ajax error and i can't stop it...it seems like there is two calls going to server but i can't find how. Because when i do submit it validate form and throw error. If i put alert in submit method...it process the error and imeediately it swiches to my home page. My quess is there is another ajax call from submit skipping validation and it does not send data and basically fails. i want to see anyone successfullyused link as submit.

Comment: FIXED. Bug is in the HTML . href="" which basically does double submit. Replaced with href="javascript:void(0);" . works ok.